# Can someone explain the workings of this Filter Board?

Tags: power-supply, analog, filter

I'm trying to understand how the power supply of an analog synthesizer (Roland Jupiter-6) works. It was built around 1983 so some of the part numbers don't yield any relevant Google results. In particular, I'm looking at the "filter board":

[image]

What is L1? The schematic symbol looks to me like a transformer, but "L" indicates that it's an inductor.

Also, what is the main function of this board? Obviously, filtering, but more specifically what kind of filtering and how does it accomplish it?

Here it is in the context of the whole power supply:

[image]

... and here's a photo of the board:

[image]

Comment: It could be a common mode pi filter. But it could equally be a differential filter. Try and find the data sheet for the murata coil (it might be 1.5 mH).

Comment: I agree with @Andy, most probable a CM filter, but can't tell for sure without any dot convention on the schematic or datasheet.

Comment: Almost certainly common mode choke. in a pi filter, as Andy says. Keeps incoming noise on the mains out of the power supply. Imagine using this synth in a TV studio or on stage with kilowatts of spots and lighting effects on triac dimmers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I finally found the datasheet, and you're right: it's a 1500 uH "Common Mode Choke Coil"